# Please explain why 17 % 40 = 17

Tags: java, operators, modulus

I am new to Java, actually programming in general.  I understand that the modulus operator (%) returns the remainder of two numbers, however, I do not understand why 17 % 40 = 17.

I understand that 40 % 17 = 6, and 17 % 5 = 2, and 40 % 5 = 0.  I get the gist of what value is returned as the remainder.  But 17 % 40 = 17 has me stumped.

The only rationalization I can devise is that since the remainder is less than 1 the total value 17 is returned, why not 0?  Please help to explain this enigma to me.

Comment: What do you mean by the remainder being less than one? The quotient is less than one. Have you confused the remainder with the quotient?

Comment: Basically, this is mathematical (Euclidean) division of integers. It's not the same as what calculator does for you, calculating the fractions. 17 can not be divided by 40 (by anything more than 17, actually), so the remainder will be the number itself. Hence, modulo operator will return the number itself if the divisor is greater than the dividend. (Pardon me if my english math terms are incorrect, studied math in a different language ;))

Comment: Try 17%18 , 17%19 , 17%20 .... 17%100 ...  17%200 .......  17%N ( where N > 17) you will get answer as 17.

Answer (score 16):

When you divide 17/40, **quotient** is 0 and the **remainder** is 17.

The **modulo operator** (`%`) returns the **remainder**.

i.e

```
a % b = remainder of a / b
```

Answer (score 1):

Equation from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) by Knuth:

[image]

```
a = 17
n = 40
floor(a/n) = 0
so r = 17
```

When `n > a` then `r` is simply `a`.

Comment: Careful.  Those equations may make his head explode :-)

Answer (score 1):

i guess learning back the 3rd and 4th standard maths is the key point.

if u see (hope understand the division syntax. its the popular 3rd std way )

```
  ____
40)17
```

you will get a reminder 17 as 17 is not divisible by 40.
then there will be an adition of '.' and then the fraction will be added

Comment: please put a reason before downvoting

Answer (score 1):

If you have the numbers *a* and *b*, their quotient *q* and remainder *r*, then the following has to be true:

*q* · *b* + *r* = *a*

That is, if you multiply the quotient (*q*) by the divisor (*b*) and add the remainder (*r*), the result is the dividend (*a*).

In your case *a* = 17, *b* = 40, *q* = 0 and so *r* has to be *17*.

Note: the equation above is just a rearrangement of the equation from [Nikolay Kuznetsov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473251/41071), but I think it's easier to understand this way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a different and more helpful way to think about it.

When we apply division to integer numbers `a` and `b`, we are really trying to relate `a` and `b` like this:

```
a = Q * b + R
```

`a` is some multiple of `b`, plus some leftover. `Q` and `R` are integers; to keep this simple, let's also just think of non-negative numbers. The multiple, `Q`, is the quotient and leftover, `R`, is the remainder -- the smallest ones that make this relation work.

In most languages, `a / b` gives you `Q`, and and `a % b` gives you `R`. (In fact processors tend to compute both at once -- these are so related.)

So if `a` is 17 and `b` is 40, it only works if you write:

```
17 = 0 * 40 + 17
```

This is why `a % b` must be 17.

(Note that it gets more complex when considering negative numbers.)